# Compression algorithm to remove redundant GPS points

Tags: algorithm, gps, compression

I have a set of longitude/latitude data which is recorded every second, and would like an algorithm which can remove any redundant coordinate points.

So for example if the driver is driving in a straight line, there's no need keep track of coordinate every second, but maybe only every half minute. Or if the driver is taking a turn, instead of having 10 coordinates in the turn, if I can have 5 and still precisely show the turn.

Comment: where you got this points from which device?

Comment: @HamitYıldırım The company I work for, made an application, which stores the longitude and latitude in a database every second.

Comment: Where you stored this data for example:
For coordinate clearification you can write a job or brocker service or trigger in sql server and oracle. Even you can look if this coordinates are exist in your db before writing them. Your questions second part links to your data store organization. For example if you stores this datas on every second for a cell there i think you need to show them on a map then while showing or reading for futher necessaties you can select this coordinates according to their axiss

Comment: @HamitYıldırım It is of no importance wich device recorded the locations. Further its is of little importance where the data are stored. He needs an compression algorithm,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an algorithm, where for a (nearly) straight line of a route only the start and endpoint of the line is stored, whereas for a curve every point is stored.

The trick is to keep track of small deviations from the straight line and to replace the current end of a straight line by the new point, as long as the line keeps straight enough and to start a new line, as soon as one of the previous points would deviate too much from the line.

Therefore my algorithm is as follows:

At the beginning the first two points are treated as the beginning of a straight line. So I am storing the start and endpoint of the line, and I am calculating the angles to the left and right of this line, which would lead to a line, where the current endpoint just has the allowed distance of lets say 2 meters.
That means if the next point lies inside the cone defined by these two angles, I can replace the previous endpoint with the new point, as the previous point will deviate from the straight line by a maximum of 2 meters.
In addition the new line again defines a cone, which must be intersected with the previous cone, so it is more and more narrowed down. As long as a new point is inside this cone, I am sure that all previous points have a maximum deviation of 2 meters.
As soon as a point comes in which lies outside the cone, the previous point "closes" the line and a new line is started consisting of the previous point and the new point.

The advantage is, that this algorithm works incrementally during recording. You do not need to store the points at first and then smooth them afterwards. The only additional information you need to keep is the current opening angle of the cone.

Answer (score 0):

If latitude and longitude is all you collect (i.e. no time or speed information) and/or you do not care that much about accuracy (i.e. you are OK with some approximation of the actual route) then determining 'redundant' points should not be a problem.

One simple approach would be to simply iterate over the points of a route (in the order the driver passed through them) and for each point `Xi` compute the distance between `Xi` and the segment `[Xi-1, Xi+1]` checking if this distance is smaller than a threshold value `T`, where `T` depends on how accurate your approximation is supposed to be. If the distance is small enough you can conclude that `Xi` is redundant and you eliminate it (or mark it for elimination).

There are a lot of variations of the above approach. One obvious one is to variate `T` depending on the length of the segment `[Xi-1, Xi+1]` and/or the position of the projection of the point `Xi` on this segment. You would probably want to eliminate `Xi` only if it is in a slim rhombus having the segment `[Xi-1, Xi+1]` as its long diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Could you please elaborate a bit more on what you mean with [Xi-1, Xi+2] ?

Comment: Xi-1 is the (i-1)th point on the route while Xi+1 is the (i+1)th one. Thus, previous and next to Xi in the order the driver passed through them.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have to delete points.  Send the first point as is, but then send each subsequent point as a *difference* from the previous point.  Set a precision on your data so that the lat and long are integers.  Use a coding scheme that takes fewer bits for small deltas.  Depending on your precision, the differences might be (0,0) a lot of the time.  Then when there is little change, it will take very few bits to represent.  Larger changes will take more bits.  You'll need some example data to get statistics for the coding scheme.